# I can't select an iOS version to test in TestFlight on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, testflight

I am trying to select the version of our app to use for TestFlight, but it will not let me select it:

It is in iTunes Connect, under TestFlight, internal testing, [image: like so]

Then you select 'Select Version to Test', and this shows up, but I can't select the version to actually test it in internal testing. Which can be seen below: [image: here]

Edit: [Here is a picture of the activity tab, as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLUZT.png)

Comment: Did you tried to click on exact the radio button? Try this. Still if you can't, just wait. May be it is apple's server problem. Should be fixed by tomorrow. I face these type of problems sometimes too.

Comment: I noticed sometime, uploading the same build once again could change things on apple side.
Can you take a screenshot of the "Activity" tab ?

Comment: @Antzi I added the activity tab, as requested

Comment: @Ujjal Alright, it would be great if it would fix itself soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build is not approved yet. It showing "Missing Beta Entitlement". Do the following steps to get it fixed.

1. Revoke your distribution provisioning profile.
2. Re-create profile again. Now in this profile a new entitlement "beta-reports-active" will be added.
3. Try submitting the build (incrementing build number by 1) with new profile. Now everything should go fine.