# iTunes Connect can't select version to test internally

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, testing, testflight

Unlike many other images of other people's iTunes Connect pages, mine is completely void of the option to select a version to test which should be where it is indicated on the screenshot below similar to the images provided by the user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242927/i-cant-select-an-ios-version-to-test-in-testflight-on-itunes-connect):[image]

I do indeed have a build so it is not a case of having no builds present:
[image]

The app does not need Beta Review approval for internal testing. Does anyone know what the possible problem could be?

Could it be a permissions issue? I am not an admin, is the visibility of some options restricted?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that being on a lowly 'Developer' role let's you basically do nothing. In order to have full privileges to select test version, add external testers etc. you need to have Admin role.